# Ms Black, Ms Blue and Ms Green - Is there really a unique answer?

Tags: combinatorics

This puzzle appeared in an article by Martin Gardner.  It goes like this:

Miss green, Miss Black and Miss Blue are out for a stroll together.  One is wearing a green dress, one a black dress and the other a blue dress.  "Isn't it odd" says Miss Blue, "that our dresses match our last names, but not one of us is wearing a dress that matches her own name".

The question is $$What\ color\ is\ each\ lady's\ dress$$ $$ $$

The solution offered in various places on the net is: $$ $$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{L/C} & \text{Black} & \text{Blue} & \text{Green} \\
\hline
\text{Ms. Black} & \text{.} & \text{Y} & \text{.} \\
\text{Ms. Blue} & \text{.} & \text{.} & \text{Y} \\
\text{Ms. Green} & \text{Y} & \text{.} & \text{.}
\end{array}
$$
$$ $$

This gives the impression that this brain teaser has a unique solution but, I don't believe that is the case.  If one reflects the above solution along the diagonal, that produces a second solution which must be correct if the first one was correct.$$ $$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{L/C} & \text{Black} & \text{Blue} & \text{Green} \\
\hline
\text{Ms. Black} & \text{.} & \text{.} & \text{Y} \\
\text{Ms. Blue} & \text{Y} & \text{.} & \text{.} \\
\text{Ms. Green} & \text{.} & \text{Y} & \text{.}
\end{array}
$$

$$ $$
It seems obvious (to me) that this problem has 2 solutions, not just one, as this brainteaser implies by simply asking "What color is each lady's dress".  That said, I thought I'd ask this question in case there is something I have missed.

Specifically, does this problem have a unique solution or not ?

**Edit**

The original puzzle adds $$"so\ what" said\ the\ lady\ in\ black$$
which causes the puzzle to have a unique solution.

See the answer by lulu below which explains why that statement makes a difference.  I originally omitted that part of the puzzle because I **mistakenly** read: "so what" said Miss Black, which makes no difference unlike when the question is asked by *the lady in black* (not Miss Black).

Comment: I agree, there are definitely two solutions. Perhaps something is missing from the puzzle? Like, is it significant that it is Mrs. Blue making the remark?

Comment: You changed the puzzle.  The original ends with the line "So what?" says the lady in black.  So we know Miss Blue isn't wearing black.

Comment: @lulu And there we have it!

Comment: You are correct, I omitted the "so what?" but, Ms. Black could ask "so what?" whether she is wearing a green or blue dress.

Comment: @Lulu You should post your comment as an answer, since the added information seals the matter!

Comment: @lulu Why does "So what ?" show that Miss blue is not wearing black ? I do not understand.

Comment: @Peter:  because the lady in black replied to Miss Blue, so she cannot be Miss Blue.

Comment: @RossMillikan OK, I realized it in the moment you made your post. A typical Gardner-puzzle!

Comment: I did not read carefully and understood " "So what ?" said Miss Black". Then, I read it again and found it out.

Comment: So far I fail to see why Miss Black asking "so what?" to Miss Blue means that she isn't wearing a blue dress.  It seems to me she could reply "so what" to Miss Blue regardless of whether she is wearing blue or green.

Comment: " 'So what?' replies the lady in black'" (replying to Miss Blue's comment), hence the Lady in in black is not Miss Blue, hence the second of the possible solution must hold, hence Miss Blue must be wearing Green.

Comment: amWhy: Now I got it :-).  It is the lady wearing black who asks "so what?" not Miss Black (as I was stuck on.) Thank you, yes, that does make a big difference in the solution. @lulu: thank you for the clear explanation.  "Had the line been spoken by Miss Black we would have learned nothing", that was the source of my misunderstanding.  I was stuck on the comment being made by Miss Black instead of "the lady in black".

Comment: Glad to help, MathAddict!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: ?? Maybe originally from article by Gardner in Games magazine (January–February, 1978).

Comment: @MaxW: TTBOMK, the reference you gave is correct.  It is the reference cited in "Mathematics - A human endeavor" by Harold R. Jacobs which is where I learned about the problem/puzzle.

Comment: Subscribed to Scientific American for years just to get Gardner's column.

Comment: Joke solution number 1: Green is wearing green, Black is wearing black, and Blue is wearing blue. Not one of them, but rather three of them, are wearing dresses that match their names. Joke solution number 2: Blue is wearing green, Green is wearing black, and Black is wearing a purple dress which Miss Blue, having protanopia (a form of color blindness), mistook for blue.

Comment: FWIW, this kind of permutation is called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). As the Wikipedia article shows, you can approximate $e$ via derangements.

Comment: The lesson here is that in these sorts of puzzles, the actual puzzle is determining which information is superfluous and which is important.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

Gardner's version of the puzzle ends with a line which is omitted here:  $$\text {"So what?", said the lady in black.}$$

Note:  a reference can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=zO4ApMb3B8QC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=martin+gardner+Miss+green,+Miss+Black+and+Miss+Blue&source=bl&ots=nHi7F5mDO5&sig=445WJAZmfBI_Z_aiamfzffghN5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidhYqWj8_SAhVQ52MKHXpAAmoQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=martin%20gardner%20Miss%20green%2C%20Miss%20Black%20and%20Miss%20Blue&f=false).

Somewhat surprisingly, that changes everything.  It adds the information that Miss Blue is not wearing black (as she wouldn't have replied to herself, nor would she have disparaged her own observation).  That makes the solution unique.

Note how delicate this information is.  Had the line been spoken by Miss Black, we'd have learned nothing.  Had it been spoken by "the lady in blue" we'd have learned nothing (as we already knew that Miss Blue was not wearing blue).

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the solution "offered in various places on the net" is the wrong one, though?

Comment: @jwodder: my mistake, after reading your comment I noticed that I put the solutions backwards.  I'm going to edit the question to reflect the solution found on the net.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options not matching. If they sit in a triangle wearing their own colours, they can rotate the dresses once and then again, both of these cases nobody wears their own.

'"So what?" said the lady in black.' Indicates that the lady in black is not Miss Blue, leaving only one possibility.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you changed the question after I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ms. Black is not wearing the black dress, she must be wearing either the green dress or the blue dress.

Suppose she is wearing the green dress.  That leaves the blue and black dresses for Ms. Blue and Ms. Green.  Ms. Blue is not wearing the blue dress so she must be wearing the black dress and Ms. Green the blue dress.

Yes, one solution is "Ms. Black is wearing the green dress, Ms. Blue is wearing the black dress, and Ms. Green is wearing the blue dress.

Suppose Ms. Black is wearing the blue dress.  That leaves the green and black dresses for Ms. Blue and Ms. Green.  Ms. Green is not wearing the green dress so she must be wearing the black dress and Ms. Blue the green dress.

Yes, another solution is "Ms. Black is wearing the green dress, Ms.  Blue is wearing the green dress, and Ms. Green is wearing the black dress.

There are two distinct solutions.